# Cumulative function definition and plotting

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I'm quite new to Mathematica. 
I have an issue defining cumulatively a function.
Let's say I have a waveform `f[t]` , and I want to create a function with many copies of it at different times. I have the list of arrival times in a vector `v`. I define my function `T` as follow

```
T[t_]:=0
For[i=1,i<=Length[v],i++,T[t]+=f[t-v[[i]]]]
```

Now, if I copy/paste the output of the last row and define a new function, I can plot it correctly, but if I call directly

```
Plot[T[t],{t,Min[v],Max[v]}]
```

My plot is empty. How's that?

Comment: Regular `Plot` plots something continuous. You want `ListPlot`. And also, try to avoid `For` loops in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `f[t]` is actually continuos. So, `Plot` is the right one. The discrete nature of the signal lies in the starting times of every copy of the **continuous** waveform I want to add to my signal. To be more specific, let say I want to add many copy of a `Sin[t]` translated in time by some given amounts, and then plot the result. Which is the best way to obtain it? Any suggestion on how to avoid the `For` loop?

Comment: Your plot is not empty, the line is superimposed to the `Axes` try `Plot[T[t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]`. You will see that `T` is defines as monotonically zero. Your `For` statement doesn't make much sense. I'm voting to close the question arises from a syntax mistake and is unlikely to help any future visitors

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake  Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what is asked. Below I am going to use `Table` since that is close to the use of the `For` loop in the question.

First we define the function f and vector v:

```
f[t_] := Sin[t]
v = Range[1, 6];
```

Next we define a function that is the sum of f over the offsets given in v:

```
T[t_] := Evaluate[Total[Table[f[t - i], {i, v}]]]
```

This is the function T:

```
In[24]:= T[t]

Out[24]= -Sin[1 - t] - Sin[2 - t] - Sin[3 - t] - Sin[4 - t] - 
 Sin[5 - t] - Sin[6 - t]
```

And here is the plot of f and T:

```
Plot[{f[t], T[t]}, {t, Min[v], Max[v]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

We can define T to use the function f and the vector of offsets v as arguments.

```
T[t_, f_, v_] := Total[Table[f[t - i], {i, v}]];
```

Here is a plot with this new definition of T:

```
Plot[{f[t], T[t, f, Range[1, 3]], T[t, f, Range[4, 13]]}, {t, Min[v], 
  Max[v]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Using `Evaluation` in the first definition of T is not necessary. Look at `Definition[T]` to evaluate the differences.